# making a scheduler in vb.net (web site)

Tags: vb.net, web

i build a website in vb.net ... i have a table process that have a begin date and end date... in the date that appropriate i want the system automatically update the data in database...

Example :

Tabel process

```
ProcessName   || begin       || End
process A     ||  02/02/2012 || 04/04/2012
```

When the current date `02/02/2012` then update table master that processName is "process A" into active and when the current date `04/04/2012` then update table master that processName is "process A" into expired.

I don't know how to create it? is anyone know about making like that?

Comment: Why you are re-editing the question? The question should be in a proper format, so the people here used to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check the status of the datetimes present in database comparing with current datetime by starting a Thread or by a Timer, and update the status also according to the datetime changes.

```
If DateTime.Now().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") = "02/02/2012" Then
  ' write a method to update the status of Process A in database.
   Update("Process A", "Active")
ElseIf DateTime.Now().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") = "04/04/2012" Then
   Update("Process A", "Expired")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return Active or Expired from the database call, according to the current date vs the value in the database.